# Probability of outcomes in a tournament

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Two players, 1 and 2, are playing a chess game which consists of a series of matches. The probability that Player 1 wins is $2/3$, and that Player 2 wins is $1/3$. The winner will be the one who is ahead of the other by 2 games and has won at least 6 games.

If Player 2 wins the first four matches, find the probability that Player 1 wins the championship.

---

The answer is given to be $1088/3645$.

Comment: This is a sum to infinity of a binomial distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player $1$ wins by winning the next $6$ games, or by winning $5$ out of the next $6$ games and then winning a pair of games before Player $2$ wins a pair of games (where we don't have to worry about any series of alternating wins in between since these just extend the match without changing the winning probabilities).

The probability to win $6$ games is $\left(\frac23\right)^6=\frac{64}{729}$. The probability to win $5$ out of $6$ games is $6\cdot\frac13\cdot\left(\frac23\right)^5=\frac{64}{243}$. The probability to win a pair of games before Player $2$ wins a pair of games is

$$
\frac{\left(\frac23\right)^2}{\left(\frac23\right)^2+\left(\frac13\right)^2}=\frac45\;.
$$

Thus the total probability is

$$
\frac{64}{729}+\frac{64}{243}\cdot\frac45=\frac{1088}{3645}\;.
$$

Comment: Cant it get extended to infinity???

Comment: @Harish: Your question mark key seems to be stuck. I'm not sure what you mean by "getting extended to infinity", but if you mean whether the number of games in the match is unbounded, the answer is yes, it is. But we don't have to deal with that, for the reason I gave in the answer.

Comment: Ok. What is the proof of this statement"where we don't have to....changing the winning probability"?

Comment: @Harish: It depends on the degree of rigour you expect from a proof. Part of what I like about probability is that it's usually more about finding elegant ways to calculate probabilities than to prove their correctness too rigourously :-) You start at $5:5$ (or $6:6$ or whatever). There are three possibilities: Either Player $1$ wins twice, or Player $2$ wins twice, or they both win once. In the third case we're back where we started, so we may as well ignore this case. The only thing that matters is whether the first or the second case occurs first.

Comment: @Harish: A slightly more formal way to put it would be: $\frac45$ is the conditional probability that Player $1$ wins twice in a row, given that one of the players wins twice in a row -- the numerator is the unconditional probability for Player $1$ to win twice in a row, and the denominator is the probability for one of the players to win twice in a row.

Comment: Let us consider a case where Player 1 wins 8 and P2  wins 2 so if the match goes to 6: then shouldnt the initial probability(from 4-0 to 6-6) be $(2/3)^6  * 1/9 * $the conditional probability that Player 1 wins 2 in a row?

Comment: @Harish: I don't know how you came up with this theory that I'd be more likely to answer your questions if you add extra question marks at the end, but I can assure you that it's wrong :-) You need to enclose math markup in dollar signs (single for inline equations, double for displayed equations); otherwise it comes out mangled as above. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: And also in those case the first selection(selecting 6 out 8 matches) again have a restriction as we cannot have Player 2 winning any 2 in the first 6(after 4-0)?That is he can only win 1 of the 6 matches and so selection is hence restricted so we cannot take $8C6$ as freely as we took $6C5$?

Comment: Hmm -- looks like you edited out the extra question mark and fixed the math a bit before I posted my reply :-)

Comment: @Harish: As to the content of your question: I'm not sure I'm following you. Could you state a bit more explicitly who wins how many matches in which order, and which part of my calculation you feel this contradicts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42057/discussion-between-harish-and-joriki).